# Poetry | AttributeError 'Link' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python-poetry

I want to install packages from `poetry.lock` file; using `poetry install`.

However, the majority of packages throw the exact same error, indicating a shared fundamental problem.

**What is causing this? What is the standard fix?**

---

**Specification:**

- Windows 10,
- Visual Studio Code,
- Python 3.8.10 & Poetry 1.1.11,
- Ubuntu Bash.

**Terminal:**

- `rm poetry.lock`
- `poetry update`
- `poetry install`

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/composite_key$ poetry update
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (217.2s)

Writing lock file

Package operations: 55 installs, 8 updates, 0 removals

  • Updating pyparsing (3.0.4 -> 2.4.7)
  • Updating pyyaml (5.4.1 -> 6.0)
  • Installing arrow (1.2.1)
  • Installing chardet (4.0.0)
  • Updating itsdangerous (1.1.0 -> 2.0.1)
  • Updating jinja2 (2.11.3 -> 3.0.2)
  • Updating packaging (20.9 -> 21.2)
  • Installing text-unidecode (1.3)
  • Updating werkzeug (1.0.1 -> 2.0.2)
  • Installing binaryornot (0.4.4)
  • Installing bokeh (2.4.1): Failed

  AttributeError

  'Link' object has no attribute 'name'

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/executor.py:632 in _download_link
      628│                 raise RuntimeError(
      629│                     "Invalid hashes ({}) for {} using archive {}. Expected one of {}.".format(
      630│                         ", ".join(sorted(archive_hashes)),
      631│                         package,
    → 632│                         archive.name,
      633│                         ", ".join(sorted(hashes)),
      634│                     )
      635│                 )
      636│

  • Updating flask (1.1.4 -> 2.0.2)
  • Installing jinja2-time (0.2.0)
  • Installing poyo (0.5.0)
  • Installing python-slugify (5.0.2)
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/composite_key$ ls
Dockerfile  azure-pipeline-composite_key.yaml  compositekey  docs  poetry.lock  pyproject.toml
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/composite_key$ poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 48 installs, 1 update, 3 removals

  • Removing cffi (1.15.0)
  • Removing colorama (0.4.4)
  • Removing pycparser (2.20)
  • Installing bokeh (2.4.1): Failed

  AttributeError

  'Link' object has no attribute 'name'

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/executor.py:632 in _download_link
      628│                 raise RuntimeError(
      629│                     "Invalid hashes ({}) for {} using archive {}. Expected one of {}.".format(
      630│                         ", ".join(sorted(archive_hashes)),
      631│                         package,
    → 632│                         archive.name,
      633│                         ", ".join(sorted(hashes)),
      634│                     )
      635│                 )
      636│
```

---

**Suggested Solution Failed:**

```
danielbellhv@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/dabell/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator$ pip install poetry==1.1.7
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting poetry==1.1.7
  Downloading poetry-1.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (173 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 173 kB 622 kB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: cachy<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-toolbelt<0.10.0,>=0.9.1 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (0.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pkginfo<2.0,>=1.4 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: shellingham<2.0,>=1.1 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tomlkit<1.0.0,>=0.7.0 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (0.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cachecontrol[filecache]<0.13.0,>=0.12.4 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (0.12.8)
Requirement already satisfied: html5lib<2.0,>=1.0 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: poetry-core<1.1.0,>=1.0.3 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: crashtest<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: clikit<0.7.0,>=0.6.2 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: keyring<22.0.0,>=21.2.0 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (21.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect<5.0.0,>=4.7.0 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cleo<0.9.0,>=0.8.1 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv<21.0.0,>=20.0.26 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (20.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging<21.0,>=20.4 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (20.9)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0,>=2.18 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from poetry==1.1.7) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: msgpack>=0.5.2 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cachecontrol[filecache]<0.13.0,>=0.12.4->poetry==1.1.7) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: lockfile>=0.9 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cachecontrol[filecache]<0.13.0,>=0.12.4->poetry==1.1.7) (0.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pastel<0.3.0,>=0.2.0 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from clikit<0.7.0,>=0.6.2->poetry==1.1.7) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pylev<2.0,>=1.3 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from clikit<0.7.0,>=0.6.2->poetry==1.1.7) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from html5lib<2.0,>=1.0->poetry==1.1.7) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from html5lib<2.0,>=1.0->poetry==1.1.7) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jeepney>=0.4.2 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from keyring<22.0.0,>=21.2.0->poetry==1.1.7) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: SecretStorage>=3.2 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from keyring<22.0.0,>=21.2.0->poetry==1.1.7) (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from packaging<21.0,>=20.4->poetry==1.1.7) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pexpect<5.0.0,>=4.7.0->poetry==1.1.7) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<3,>=2 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenv<21.0.0,>=20.0.26->poetry==1.1.7) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenv<21.0.0,>=20.0.26->poetry==1.1.7) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.2 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenv<21.0.0,>=20.0.26->poetry==1.1.7) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.entry-points-selectable>=1.0.4 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from virtualenv<21.0.0,>=20.0.26->poetry==1.1.7) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from SecretStorage>=3.2->keyring<22.0.0,>=21.2.0->poetry==1.1.7) (2.8)
Installing collected packages: poetry
Successfully installed poetry-1.1.7
danielbellhv@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/dabell/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator$ pip install poetry-core==1.0.4
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: poetry-core==1.0.4 in /home/danielbellhv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.0.4)
danielbellhv@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/dabell/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator$ poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 82 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing certifi (2021.5.30): Pending...
  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
  • Installing certifi (2021.5.30): Failed
  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3

  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
  JSONDecodeError
  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3

  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3

  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
      397│                 idx += 1
  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
      399│                 idx += 3
  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
      401│ 
  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3

  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.3): Failed

  JSONDecodeError

  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

  at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py:400 in raw_decode
      396│             if ord0 == 0xfeff:
      397│                 idx += 1
      398│             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
      399│                 idx += 3
    → 400│         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
      401│ 

  • Installing idna (3.2): Failed
...

  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8): Failed
...

  • Installing urllib3 (1.26.6): Failed
...
```

---

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post.

Comment: The error seems to suggest that you poetry.lock file is out of synch with you pyproject.toml. Usually just deleting the poetry.lock file and running poetry install again will fix the issue.

Comment: Huge improvement! There's now only one instance of this error left. Updated post

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I'm back to where I once was... I ran `poetry update` and then `poetry install` again. Really strange behaviour

Comment: Now I've deleted `poetry.lock`, `poetry update` and `poetry install`. Post updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks to be an active issue relating to poetry. See [here - Issue #4085](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4085). Some suggest a workaround by downgrading `poetry-core` down to 1.0.4.

There is an active [PR](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/5326) to fix the issue.

Comment: `pip install poetry-core==1.0.4`... However, `poetry add ...` or `poetry install` threw: `bash: /home/me/.local/bin/poetry: No such file or directory`

Comment: Have you also tried downgrading poetry to 1.1.7?

Comment: no I meant poetry==1.1.7 with poetry-core==1.0.4

Comment: yup exactly in that order. It will install `poetry=1.1.7` first, then downgrade from `poetry-core=1.0.7` to `1.0.4`.

Comment: I'm able to replicate issues on my end trying to create a project with just Bokeh in it. No variation of the poetry version seems to work!

Comment: Clarifying solution: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4701#issuecomment-970423634

Answer (score 23):

In my case (poetry 1.1.6) I solved it by clearing the artifacts cache before `poetry install`:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/*
```